# Angular ng-repeat html list not updating even though the actual array changes in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items being displayed on a page using ng-repeat. Below is the html.

```
    <div class="container-fluid"> 

        <div class="container" >

            <div class="page-header">
                <h3>Found {{searchResults.length}} results that match your search <br /><small>Click on any result to view details</small></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in searchResults">
                <a ng-href="/#/details/{{item.test_catalog_cd}}.json" class="list-group-item">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.test_name}}</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text" ng-bind-html="item.synonyms"></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This array is created when the application loads. Below is the function in the controller where the array is modified.

```
$scope.onClickSearch = function () {
    console.log("Search Click in Controller - " + $scope.searchString);
    $scope.searchResults = new Array();

    /*
        remove special characters and html tags from the synonyms and check if the name 
        or synonym contains the search string.
    */
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            var synonyms = $scope.items[i].synonyms
            var testName = $scope.items[i].test_name.toLowerCase();
            if ((testName.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1) || (synonyms.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1)) {
                var searchItem = $scope.items[i];
                $scope.searchResults.push(searchItem);
            }
        };
        $location.url("/search");
    });
    console.log($scope.searchResults); //Array is shown to be updated here.
```

When the function updates the array, the html displayed on the page does not change. [image: That is what I see.]

**UPDATE:**
Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co:443/t0CjyI8RG5d5tm2qGXDp) with the recreated issue. When I type in something to search and hit the search button, The view does not show the search results.

Comment: in the console is no error?

Comment: no error on console

Comment: yes. the log is showing correctly.

Comment: `});` where is it opening or am I missing sth?

Comment: that was the closing parentheses for `$scope.$apply(function(){ })` I was trying to see if restarting the digest cycle made any difference. Sorry about that.

Comment: why do you need `$location.url("/search");`? if you set a url the controller will reset and the array is empty again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133120/discussion-between-pparas-and-rala).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29423/ seems to work fine to me?

Comment: I think my issue might be because of the `$location.url` statement. Not sure how though

Comment: @Dylan I have this as a .net project. with my ngView encapsulated in a content place holder. Could that have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a tracking issue -- consider using the "track by" syntax to update the tracking.

More information on the ngRepeat docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat